# How to pass reference to function in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, vb6

I have a program that already written in VB6, now I need to change it to VB.NET, but I got `System.AccessViolationException` error.

VB6

```
Public result(512) As Byte
Private Declare Function getInfo Lib "abc" Alias "_GetInfo@12" (ByVal uiCom As Long, ByVal uiParam As Long, ucResult As Any) As Long
Dim isSuccess As Long
isSuccess = getInfo(0, 1, result(0))
```

VB.NET

```
Public result(512) As Byte
Private Declare Function getInfo Lib "abc" Alias "_GetInfo@12" (ByVal uiCom As Long, ByVal uiParam As Long, ucResult As Object) As Long
Dim isSuccess As Long
isSuccess = getInfo(0, 1, result(0))
```

Is it because the result is passing the value not the reference to function?

Comment: You would just pass `result` rather than `result(0)` and you may have to declare that parameter `ByRef`.

Comment: A Long in VB6 is an Integer in VB.NET.  The last argument is ByRef.  As Any is pretty tricky, you surely at least ought to use `<MarshalAs>` so you can declare it UnmanagedType.AsAny.  YMMV.

Comment: Changed to `Private Declare Function getInfo Lib "abc" Alias "_GetInfo@12" (ByVal uiCom As Long, ByVal uiParam As Long, ByRef ucResult As Object) As Long` & `isSuccess = getInfo(0, 1, result)` but still not working. Also how to use `<MarshalAs>` to declare? Could you give some example? Thanks a lot.